# Should or would

Tags: modal-verbs, should

Is it
I should be grateful for an early response
or 
I would be grateful for an early response.
In formal UK English it is the former but even there I see it less often these days.
Since I was brought up on UK English
I should be grateful for an early response.

Comment: I see little difference between [British](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+would+be+grateful+if%2CI+should+be+grateful+if&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20would%20be%20grateful%20if%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20should%20be%20grateful%20if%3B%2Cc0) and [American](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+would+be+grateful+if%2CI+should+be+grateful+if&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20would%20be%20grateful%20if%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20should%20be%20grateful%20if%3B%2Cc0) trends on this.

Comment: Thank you for rejecting this on grounds it is duplicate. If you went to the Hansard (the record of British Houses of Parliament) you will see a lot of *should*. I have gone and edited and responded to people who have answered many of my questions and I *should* be grateful if the question-bar on me is lifted.

Comment: I don't understand (is that a *sarcastic* "Thank you"? :). Are you saying you want this question reopened because the answers to that earlier question don't resolve your problem?

Comment: Sorry for missing out the full stop after thank you. Without it sarcasm can be read. What I want is to be readmitted to pose questions and hence I have gone down all mine to edit them. Some I am dropping.

Comment: I'm not a mod, so I don't know anything about why you might want to be *readmitted to pose questions*. That seems to imply you are or were *suspended* from the site, but I know nothing of that. But you can't normally *delete* your own questions once other people have responded to them by posting answers, so if that's what you're trying to do I suggest you either start a chat thread with a mod, or post a question on meta asking for help.